# Regex for validating currency number format

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

I've got following formats, that are acceptable

```
1200000,00
1200000.00
1,200,000.00
1 200 000.00
1 200 000,00
1 200 000,0000
-1 200 000.00
```

At the moment I was able to verify only `^-?\\d+$`, `^-?\\d+[\\,\\.]\\d{2}$`, `^-?\\d+[\\,\\.]\\d{2,}$`. Two last format are separate, so that I would know is rounding needed or not. All three format use `gm` flags to check string from start `^` to end `$`.

Those regular expressions cover only first two elements in list. Other elements, that use commas and spaces for thousand separation are not verified yet and I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Also there is a "beautifier" expression `(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))`, that will take this `1200000,00` and turn it into `1 200 000,00` with such usage `'1200000,00'.replace(('(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))', 'g'), '$1 ')`.

So question states, what would be a correct regular expression to validate such format `1 200 000.00` or `1,200,000.00`? Since I assume difference with `\s\,` could be easily done in same expression.

Thank you.

Comment: How about enforcing the use of one consistent format, instead of having to write overly complex logic to allow all those?

Comment: Those are the requirements, that can't be changed by me.

Comment: i used numeral.js for that

Comment: @johnSmith this is a good library(I assume), but it is for applying  correct format, rather then validating given. Sure there could be a hack used like `startValue.apply(format) === startValue`, that would tell wether correct format was past or not, but it is a hack IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For validating the last two numbers, you can use the following:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(?:[\s,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?$
  1  2         3     4      5
```

[image: Visualization]

1. Optional minus sign
2. 1..3 digits
   Zero or more fragments that consist of
3. comma or space
4. 3 digits
5. optional fraction part consisting of a dot followed by 1 or more digits.

Comment: Pretty awesome. I for some reason was trying to use lookaheads to achieve, that result. Thank you very much.

Comment: seems, that I found a small error in logic. It looks like http://www.regexr.com/39gu5, if one allowing last part not to be present at all, allows second part to be as last. So this will validate `1 234,245`, since last part validates to `(?:[\s,]\d{3})*`

Answer (score 2):

> <sub>This doesn't directly solve the problem due to me misreading. But it might still be useful to someone so I'll let it stay.</sub>

Stop trying to solve every problem with regex. Regex is great when you have one or two very well defined strings. Not a million formats.

This can be solved with minimal regex. Magic is in the bold part.

```
var numbers = [
    "1200000,00",
    "1200000.00",
    "1,200,000.00",
    "1 200 000.00",
    "1 200 000,00",
    "1 200 000,0000",
    "-1 200 000.00"
];

var parseWeirdNumber = function(numberString) {
    //Split numbers to parts. , . and space are all valid delimiters.
    var numberParts = numberString.split(/[.,\s]/);
    //Remove the last part. **This means that all input must have fraction!!**
    var fraction = numberParts.pop();
    //Rejoin back without delimiters, and reapply the fraction.
    //parseFloat to convert to a number
    var number = parseFloat(numberParts.join('') + "." + fraction);
    return number;
}

numbers = numbers.map(parseWeirdNumber);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Isn't that formatting? Or you propose same usage of formatting as I described in previous comment?

Comment: The `parseWeirdNumber` function will parse all of your examples correctly.